# Don't set language cookie in Django

Tags: django, cookies, internationalization, translation

We're trying to avoid setting the Django language cookie, as this is the only cookie our site uses, and we want to avoid the legal liability of setting cookies. But I can't seem to find a way to prevent Django from setting this cookie.

Comment: Maybe try [Django - Language prefix in URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns)

Comment: Also I’m curious about that law that forbid setting language cookie… Could you add a link + citation or a country name…?

Comment: @Zatigem There isn't a law that forbids setting language cookies, but there are laws in a few countries which require sites to obtain user permission before setting cookies. We don't want to have to implement obtaining user permissions.